# Can a scala type class have abstract type members?

Tags: scala, generics, types, typeclass, abstract-type

I have this type class:

```
sealed trait DbValueOps[T <: DbValue] {
  type R
  def apply(newContent: R): Option[T]
  def fromString(newContent: String): Option[T]
  def isValidContent(newContent: R): Boolean
}
```

with this type class instance:

```
package object DbOps {
  implicit val dbStringOps: DbValueOps[DbString] = new DbValueOps[DbString] {
    type R = String
    def apply(newContent: String): Option[DbString] =
      isValidContent(newContent) match {
        case true => Some(new DbString(newContent))
        case false => None
      }
    def fromString(newContent: String): Option[DbString] = this(newContent)
    def isValidContent(newContent: String): Boolean = !newContent.isEmpty
  }
}
```

But when trying to use the type class instance with something like `dbStringOps.isValidContent(newContent)` where newcontent is a string, i get a type mismatch:

```
found   : newContent.type (with underlying type String)
required: database.DbOps.dbStringOps.R
```

I can get it to work by converting R from an abstract type member to a type parameter, but that is ugly since R is already determined when i'm writing the implementation of the type class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add type annotations on that `implicit val`.

```scala
implicit val dbStringOps: DbValueOps[DbString] { type R = String } = ...
```

or

receive implicit parameter using this signature.

```scala
def f()(implicit db: DbValueOps[DbString] { type R = String }) = ...
```

can also write like this.

```scala
type AUX[A, T] = DbValueOps[A] { type R = T }

def f()(implicit db: AUX[DbString, String]) = ...
```

Comment: When are those type annotations necessary? Is it always when using abstract type members in type classes?

And what is: `type AUX[A, T] = DbValueOps[A] { type R = T }` called? I don't exactly understand what that does.

Comment: How do i now make classes with methods generic over dbValueOps? I'm trying to do so with a class definition like:`case class Column[R, T <: DbValue[R]] private (...)(implicit ops: DbValueOps){`
And a method like: `  def createDbValue(): T = {
    ops.fromString("hi").get
  }`
But i get the error: `found: Column.this.ops.T, required: T`

Comment: I ended up ditching the abstract type members in dbValueOps (still have one in dbValue though) because i want to use them in a generic way in other classes, and i don't know how to get the information of what the return type of the functions in dbValueOps are into those other classes without using type parameters

Comment: I'm doing so like this: `case class Column[R, T <: DbValue[R, T]] private (...)(implicit ops: DbValueOps[R, T]) {`

This did kind of accomplish my goal of forcing there to be an associated dbValueOps typeclass instance, but i don't like that i have to explictly pass the typeclass object.

Answer (score 4):

恵砂川 answer solves your problem perfectly, but unless you really want to center your design on DbValues, I will suggest to center your implicit on the wrapped value (String on this case), as you don't need to provide the unification of R with String.

```
  trait DbValue[T]
  case class DbString(s:String) extends DbValue[String]


  sealed trait DbOps[R]{
    type T <: DbValue[R]
    def apply(newContent: R): Option[T]
    def fromString(newContent: String): Option[T]
    def isValidContent(newContent: R): Boolean
  }

  object DbOps {
    val dbStringOps: DbOps[String] = new DbOps[String] {
      type T = DbString
      def apply(newContent: String): Option[DbString] =
        isValidContent(newContent) match {
          case true => Some(new DbString(newContent))
          case false => None
        }
      def fromString(newContent: String): Option[DbString] = this(newContent)
      def isValidContent(newContent: String): Boolean = !newContent.isEmpty
    }

    val newContent = "hello"
    dbStringOps.isValidContent(newContent)
  }
```

Adding a type parameter to DbValue can be a little more verbose but it prevents you to define things like  `DbValueOps[DbString] { type R = Int }` that probably is NOT what are you looking for.

Comment: I have accepted 恵砂川 's answer, because they directly answered my question, but I will be going with your design!